# Как мне удалить элемент из массива лемматизированых слов?

Tags: python, aiogram, pymorphy2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне удалять элемент из массива с лемматезороваными словами после 'не'. Буду очень благодарен.
Вот отрвок из моего кода

```
async def work(message: Message):
    morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
    text = message.text
    text=text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    Massiv = text.split()    /*массив с сообщением*/
    for i in Massiv:
        p = morph.parse(i)[0]
        print(p.normal_form)    /*лемматизированный элемент массива*/ 
        if(p.normal_form=='не'):
            for i in Massiv:
                p = morph.parse(i)[0]
                if(p.normal_form=='боевик' or p.normal_form=='фантастика'):
                    Massiv.remove(i)    /*удалить 1 элемент который соответствует условию*/ 
                    break
```

Comment: Зачем у вас тут цикл в цикле? Логика непонятна. Лучше сначала сформулируйте, что вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: мне нужно удалить совпадения из массива после элемента 'не'

Comment: Так вы не после, а заново весь массив перебираете. Тут надо всё продумать